# Using jQuery to input something in Redactor

Tags: javascript, jquery, editor, wysiwyg

I have a textarea field with an id called "description". But it's rendered by a WHYSIWYG editor called redactor.

How can I use jquery to input something in the textarea?

I tried:

> $('#description').val('hello').blur();

and

> $('#description').val('hello');

But both not works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the setCode method is what you need.
Just check it out at the documentation: http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/api/

```
$('#description').setCode ('<p>hello</p>');
```